# Android Location Permission

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions, location-services

I am using these two permissions in my application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have added the permission in the manifest. However, when I debug into my phone, i try to check the permission using the function below:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("permission","done");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        // The ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is denied, then I request it and manage the result in
        // onRequestPermissionsResult() using the constant MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

    }
```

The application will enter the first IF statement, instead of requesting permission from the user.
I didn't grant any permission to this application before.
Why is the permission become GRANTED even if i just debug and install the application in my phone?

Comment: Because the runtime permission is added in Marshmallow and not in the previous versions, so if you have added the permission in the manifest it will automatically grant permission and don't even ask for the permission at runtime unless it's Marshmallow device

Comment: You're testing on Android M, right?

Comment: No. Im testing on galaxy note 5.

Comment: I mean the version of Android running on the device.  Is it M (6.0)?

Comment: Nope. Its running on Lollipop 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the runtime permission is added in Marshmallow and not in the previous versions, so if you have added the permission in the manifest it will automatically grant permission and don't even ask for the permission at runtime unless it's Marshmallow device.

Comment: I'm testing on Galaxy Note 5. How do i get the request permission dialog to actually ask for permission?

Comment: I tried to remove the <uses permission> in android manifest and the request dialog still won't pop up.

Comment: I haven't tried to ask runtime permission below android M. Android auto manage the permission if it is declared in the Manifest.